# Windows Developer Dashboard: No app listed in push notification

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I have some UWP app published in windows store, I want to send push notification to app user. I have configured app for push notification as described on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/configure-your-app-to-receive-dev-center-notifications), but there is not any app listed on developer dashboard (Engage > Notification > Blank Template). Is there anything I missed to configured? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can find the app, you should **associated your app with th store** firstly. So you should create an new app or you have had an app on the **Dev Center** to make your app associate.

In Visual Studio, you can associate you app by the steps: Right click your app project => Store => Associate App with the Store... then select the app you want to associate. After that, may be you need to wait some seconds, then you should be able to find your app to send the notification.

Comment: Hi Breeze thanks for answer, I have associated app with the store, and they are published.

Comment: Please associate your app with the store again and run your app to call the `RegisterNotificationChannelAsync` method at least once to register your app to receive notifications. Then you can try to find your app again.